# (Laravel) método $.get não consegue encontrar rota

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, get

Eae pessoal, tudo certo?

Gostaria bastante da ajuda de vocês pois já estou preso neste problema há uns dois dias e não consegui resolver sozinho.

Tenho uma tabela com várias linhas e com um checkbox em cada linha e um botão que, quando clicado, pega todas as linhas que estão selecionadas, armazena os ids dessas linhas em um array, transforma o array em um json e faz uma requisição a uma rota passando este json, onde será manipulado para percorrer todos os ids e fazer alterações no banco de dados.

Inicialmente funcionava tranquilamente, mas de um tempo pra cá parou de funcionar, não sei porque.

**Função javascript** (na view):

```
    function tornarPendente() {

    var arrayIds = [];

    //pega todos os checkbox que estão selecionados e para cada um pega o ID referente ao aluno
    $.each($('.checkbox1').prop('checked', 'checked'), function() {
        var id = ($(this).attr('id'));
            arrayIds.push(id);  //coloca no vetor de ids
    });

    //converte o array em um json para passar para a rota
    var json = {
        "ids": arrayIds
    };

    $.get('../controle/concluidas/tornarTodasPendentes', json, function(data) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    });

}
```

**Rota**

```
Route::get('/controle/concluidas/tornarTodasPendentes/', function() {
$input = Input::only('ids'); //recebe um array de ids
$input = $input['ids']; 
foreach($input as $id) {
    $aluno = new App\Aluno();
    $aluno = $aluno->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    $aluno->pendente = '1';
    $aluno->save();
}
    return Redirect::back();
```

});

OBS: Estranho mesmo é o fato de que se eu alterar o endereço da rota para uma rota que não existe, o javascript não me retorna nenhum erro (mesmo se eu retirar a parte do window.location.reaload(true) ).

OBS2: Se eu der um alert(json['ids']) consigo ver os ids normalmente.

Existe alguma forma de eu saber se esses ids pelo menos chegaram à rota?

Qualquer tipo de ajuda será bem-vinda.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Falou, falou, falou mas não falou qual erro retorna.. rsrsr. Já verificou o óbvio? Por exemplo, se a url está correta no ajax?  Está apontando o caminho de forma relativa. Pode ser que esteja apontando para um caminho inexistente ou errado.. enfim.. Para auxiliar no debug use o console do "developer tools" do seu browser. No chrome, `Ctrl+Shift+I`

Comment: Então, amigo, conforme eu falei na obs 1, o javascript não me retorna nenhum erro (no console do developer tools), e mais estranho ainda é que ele não me retorna nenhum erro nem quando eu altero essa url para uma rota que não existe.
Por isso eu queria saber se tem como eu verificar se os dados foram mesmo passados para a rota ou não, através do PHP.
As rotas estão corretas, inclusive esta função funcionava antes de alguma alteração que eu fiz, mas agora não estão mais funcionando...
De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Reverta a alteração que fez até o ponto onde funcionava então analise o que a alteração poderia ter causado.

Comment: Sobre não retornar erro, não ficou claro o que retorna. É isso que quis dizer. Se não retorna erro, o que retorna então? Página em branco? Uma mensagem? Qual o status http? enfim.. difícil saber sem ter os parâmetros..

Comment: Para ver a depuração no console do browser, o PHP não tem nada a ver. Abra o developer tools do browser (FF, Chrome, IE) e analise os headers algo do tipo. Geralmente fica em "Network". No Chrome é "Network" -> "Doc". Então vc clica no documento que deseja analisar e veja os logs. Uma dica, ao invés de usar `alert()` para depurar, use o `console.debug(json['ids'])`, por exemplo. Não que isso vá resolver algo, mas é um jeito melhor de depurar.

Comment: Outro jeito bem grotesco de testar, vá no index.php do laravel e mete um `print_r($_GET); exit;` bem no início, só para testar. Se receber então está de boa. O problema não deve ser código javascript. Aí vc já pula uma etapa e não perde tempo no javascript. Deve ser algo que mecheu nos codigos no laravel conforme você mesmo mencionou.

Comment: Tentei reverter a alteração, usando o git checkout para o commit antigo, de seis dias atrás, inclusive, mas não alterou nada.

Sobre o erro, a página fica estática se eu retirar a linha 'window.location.reload(true)', mas em network aparece uma nova linha como se tivesse OK, passando os ids, tudo certo. 
Inclusive com um Status Code: OK (verde). Em Query String Parameters passa todos os parâmetros de forma normal (todos os ids).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica de usar o console.debug, farei isso futuramente.

Sobre o print_r($_GET); exit; no início do arquivo index.php, não altera nada quando eu clico no botão que faz a requisição GET, a página fica estática do jeito que estava. Isso, é claro, se eu comentar esses comandos até chegar na página desejada e descomentar apenas na hora de clicar no botão, após selecionadas as linhas da tabela. Caso contrário, se eu deixar os comandos quando eu entro na página, tenho apenas uma paǵina em branco escrito Array().

De qualquer forma, obrigado!

Comment: Aparece somente como `array()`? então não estaria recebendo como POST ao invés de GET? tente `print_r($_REQUEST); exit;`.  E ao invés de testar pelo ajax, joga diretamente na barra de url do browser. .enfim.. vai fuçando e buscando onde tem o problema, sacou? Claro, não esqueça de limpar a bagunça com essses `print_r` e `exit` né..

Answer (score 4):

Usando o `../` pode ocasionar problemas se você estivar numa rota com um sub-segmento.

Por exemplo,

localhost:8000/admin/../teste/1

É o mesmo que

```
 localhost:8000/teste/1
```

Já nesse caso:

```
localhost:8000/admin/acao/../test
```

O resultado seria;

```
localhost:8000/admin/test
```

No `Laravel`, por ser tratar de uma aplicação que sempre é rodada na "raiz" do seu host, não é necessário usar `../`.

Talvez seja isso que esteja ocasionando seu problema.

Comment: Isso mesmo o problema esta em `../` ;)

Comment: Agradeço as respostas, mas acredito que essa ainda não seja a solução do meu problema =(

Veja: utilizando "../controle/concluidas/tornarTodasPendentes" ou sem os dois pontos, quando eu vou verificar em 'network' do google chrome, a request url é a mesma: "http://localhost/controle/concluidas/tornarTodasPendentes?ids..." e os parametros do get. Já tentei, inclusive, colocar um 'die('teste')' na rota, mas nem é executado. Tentei também criar uma função em um controller e usar este controller na rota, mas não funciona.

Comment: Na aba 'response' (dentro de network), após o get, tenho apenas o código html / javascript da página em que estou

Answer (score 0):

foi tudo uma grande confusão de rotas...

Como eu havia dito, ocorreu depois que eu fiz um recurso novo (que era uma funcao para fazer um select em ascendente e descendente), que usava uma rota **/controle/pendentes/{ascDesc?}**
que ia para o controller alunoController@controlePendentes

Isso fazia com que qualquer rota em /controle/pendentes/QualquerCoisa fosse pra este controller, inclusive a rota que eu tinha criado pra tornar todas concluidas, visto que a rota era: **/controle/pendentes/concluirVarias**

Agora alterei a rota para

**/controle/concluirVarias**, o que faz com que caia no controller correto...

Agradeço demais a ajuda de vocês, pela paciência...

Abraço!